# Websocket over wss:// disconnects without any errors

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I am making a webcoket application for my website. Evrything were OK before I tried secured connection.
Chrome just disconnects with "undefined" error.
Server console shows

> 2014-07-25 15:24:50 [info] [client 5.ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ:54166] Connected
>
> 2014-07-25 15:24:50 [info] [client 5.ХХХ.ХХХ.ХХХ:54166] Disconnected

My server is running CentOS 6 with Apache and PHP 5.4.
For WS server I choose [Link1](https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket)
Certificate also was built for TSL. What I am doing wrong?
You can check it out on [Link2](https://ws.d1xn.ru/en.php)

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Well, the browser is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I replaced built-in SSL with stunnel.